# Android SharedPreferences not getting changed through editor.commit

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to change a preference when I click on another preference. I did this with `onSharedPreferenceChanged` method and setting the value with editor like this...

```
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sp, String key) {
    Preference pref = findPreference(key);

    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

    editor.putString("sound","2");
    editor.commit();
    Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, Prefer.class);
    startActivity(intent3);  
    this.setSummary(pref);
```

However, I am getting an error at `editor.commit();` and my code runs in the background for several times before giving StatckOverflow error... What am I doing wrong?

Than You

Comment: What is the error, can you copy logcat logs

Answer (score 7):

Your calling ,

```
 onSharedPreferenceChanged
```

then your calling

```
 editor.commit();
```

By commit() you are changing your shared preferences and therefore calling

```
 onSharedPreferenceChanged
```

and so the cycle continues ..... till you StackOverflow

*[My Christmas SharedPreferences API Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html#onSharedPreferenceChanged%28android.content.SharedPreferences,%20java.lang.String%29) *